# How to update a byte array in a method, without running it again?

Tags: java, android, methods, ffmpeg, byte

I have a class(an `AsyncTask`) which does image processing and generates yuv bytes continously, at around ~200ms interval.

Now I send these yuv bytes to another method where the they are recorded using FFmpeg frame recorder:

```
public void recordYuvData() {

        byte[] yuv = getNV21();
        System.out.println(yuv.length + "  returned yuv bytes  ");
        if (audioRecord == null || audioRecord.getRecordingState() != AudioRecord.RECORDSTATE_RECORDING) {
            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            return;
        }
        if (RECORD_LENGTH > 0) {
            int i = imagesIndex++ % images.length;
            yuvimage = images[i];
            timestamps[i] = 1000 * (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
        }
        /* get video data */
        if (yuvimage != null && recording) {
            ((ByteBuffer) yuvimage.image[0].position(0)).put(yuv);

            if (RECORD_LENGTH <= 0) {
                try {
                    long t = 1000 * (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
                    if (t > recorder.getTimestamp()) {
                        recorder.setTimestamp(t);
                    }
                    recorder.record(yuvimage);
                } catch (FFmpegFrameRecorder.Exception e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This method; recordYuvData() is initiated on button click.

1. If I initiate it only once , then only the initial image gets recorded, rest are not.
2. If I initiate this each time after the end of the image processing it records but leads to 'weird' fps count of the video; and finally this leads to application crash after sometime.

   For above what I feel is, at the end of image processing a new instance of recordYuvData() is created without ending the previous one, accumulating many instances of recordYuvData(). [correct me if I am wrong]

So, how do I update 'ONLY' yuv bytes in the method without running it again?

Thanks....!

**Edit:**

On Click:

```
    record.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            recordYuvdata();
            startRecording();
```

getNV21()

```
byte[] getNV21(Bitmap bitmap) {

    int inputWidth = 1024;
    int inputHeight = 640;
    int[] argb = new int[inputWidth * inputHeight];

    bitmap.getPixels(argb, 0, inputWidth, 0, 0, inputWidth, inputHeight);
    System.out.println(argb.length + "@getpixels ");


    byte[] yuv = new byte[inputWidth * inputHeight * 3 / 2];
    encodeYUV420SP(yuv, argb, inputWidth, inputHeight);

    return yuv;

}

void encodeYUV420SP(byte[] yuv420sp, int[] argb, int width, int height) {
    final int frameSize = width * height;

    int yIndex = 0;
    int uvIndex = frameSize;
    System.out.println(yuv420sp.length + " @encoding " + frameSize);

    int a, R, G, B, Y, U, V;
    int index = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {

            a = (argb[index] & 0xff000000) >> 24; // a is not used obviously
            R = (argb[index] & 0xff0000) >> 16;
            G = (argb[index] & 0xff00) >> 8;
            B = (argb[index] & 0xff) >> 0;

            // well known RGB to YUV algorithm

            Y = ((66 * R + 129 * G + 25 * B + 128) >> 8) + 16;
            U = ((-38 * R - 74 * G + 112 * B + 128) >> 8) + 128;
            V = ((112 * R - 94 * G - 18 * B + 128) >> 8) + 128;

            // NV21 has a plane of Y and interleaved planes of VU each sampled by a factor of 2
            //    meaning for every 4 Y pixels there are 1 V and 1 U.  Note the sampling is every other
            //    pixel AND every other scanline.
            yuv420sp[yIndex++] = (byte) ((Y < 0) ? 0 : ((Y > 255) ? 255 : Y));
            if (j % 2 == 0 && index % 2 == 0) {
                yuv420sp[uvIndex++] = (byte) ((V < 0) ? 0 : ((V > 255) ? 255 : V));
                yuv420sp[uvIndex++] = (byte) ((U < 0) ? 0 : ((U > 255) ? 255 : U));
            }

            index++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your button code, please. Also, please post your `getNV21` method

Comment: Why do you call getNV21() without any parameters?

Comment: It expects a Bitmap parameter.

Comment: That is present in different part of code,....

Comment: sorry its like this byte [] getNV21() { Bitmap bitmap = Bitmapdata()..... }

Comment: First, you should not do this on the main thread. My suggestion is that on click you start a thread that will read data from image processing task and send it to the ffmpeg recorder ( until maybe stop is pressed? ). In this thread you can have a `while(recording)` loop that will execute recordYuvData().

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestion, I will give a try...!